# How can I use a passed parameter in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

Forgive the *complete* newbie question here - I *know* this is really basic stuff, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  Javascript is relatively new to me, and this is the first time I've had to do this particular thing.

So, I'm trying to use a Modal to open an iframe - the page itself will have links to several modals, all of which need to be passed a different value.  Rather than hardcode each of these, I'm trying to set it up in such a way that one function can be used and the links can pass the values as required.

The code I currently have successfully opens the modal, but a 404 error is inside it - plus the modal title shows + title + - so I guess I'm referencing it wrong (probably in the function?).

Heres what I've got, pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
function openIframe(title,url){
    $.modal({
        title: '+title+',
        url: '+url+',
        useIframe: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    });
}
```

.. and the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openIframe('Process Voucher','a_processvoucher.cfm')">Add</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the variables, don't quote them; `title` was being *literally* set to the string `+title+` (and the same for `url`).

```
function openIframe(title, url) {
    $.modal({
        title: title,
        url: url,
        useIframe: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    });
}​
```

It seemed you were getting confused over the concatenation syntax to join strings and variables; for example, see the following:

```
var name = "Matt";
var welcome = "Hi " + name +  ", how are you doing today?";
alert(welcome);
```

... will alert the string `Hi Matt, how are you doing today?`

Comment: Thank you! That sorted it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to reference the variables called `title` and `url`, not strings with the values "title" and "url"

```
function openIframe(title,url) {
    $.modal({
        title: title, // no quotes
        url: url, // no quotes
        useIframe: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    });
}
```